# How can I load Google Data Studio into Presenter Mode?

Tags: url, raspberry-pi, looker-studio

I am creating a Google Data Studio dashboard that is supposed to be on a constant display on a screen in my office. The dashboard runs on a Raspberry Pi which currently boots into fullscreen Chromium with the dashboard as starting page and refreshes the page every 60 minutes. Unfortunately the URL only opens the dashboard with the control tab on the top. Is there any way to include a parameter in the URL that automatically opens the "Present" mode such that there are no controls on top and with the automatic sheet change every 60 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Use a click automation tool like "[Pullover's Macro Creator](https://www.macrocreator.com/)" to automate the presentation mode button click.